# PanelBar expands too far, then slides up

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I have a panelbar which displays a few divs/ULs.  The lists, when their width is set to 40%, for example, cause the panelbar to slide farther down than it should, and then jump back up to where it 'should' be.  Remove the 40% on the UL, and everything works as expected.

Version 2015.3.930 has this issue, whereas older versions (randomly picked 2011.3.1407) do not.

```
<ul class="doctypecontainer noselect">
    <li style="clear:both;">
        <span>Truck Freight Bill (1)</span>

        <div class="doctypecontainercontent">
            <div class="docdatelabel"><input type="checkbox" />10/27/2015</div>
            <ul class="pagelist">
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 1</span></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 2</span></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 3</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="pagelist">
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 4</span></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 5</span></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 6</span></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="docdatelabel"><input type="checkbox" />11/15/2015</div>
            <ul class="pagelist">
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 1</span></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 2</span></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 3</span></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="docdatelabel"><input type="checkbox" />11/21/2015</div>
            <ul class="pagelist">
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 1</span></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 2</span></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" /><span>Page 3</span></li>
            </ul>

            <span style="clear:left; display:block;"></span>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/u48kLrem/

remove the width:40% from the pagelist class, and it slides as expected.

Comment: where is the pagelist class in the fiddle  ? fiddle is diff.

Comment: Ah, nuts. I put the wrong link.  It's been updated.

Comment: This is due to the applied `display:none` of the container and the `float:left` property. The control does not calculate the height correctly. You should remove the width property, on its place you could add `padding-right` to have the same distance between the groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, man.  I suspect that it has to do with the text wrapping (or something wrapping) and causing it to miscalculate the height.  Probably just bad coding on their part, but a simple modification causes the jump to disappear.  Also, this modification should make it more reliable/future-proofed too.

```
.pagelist {
    padding-bottom:5px;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left:10px;
    width: 50%; /* change this to 50% */
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* add this to force it to calculate
                               the padding in with the width to
                               total 50% */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/2ekxpuu6/

Comment: Hey, looks like that does it. Thanks much.  Out of curiosity, why is it more reliable/future proofed?

Comment: @BrianM. in most cases 50% + 50% is more likely to always equal 100% rather than 40% + 40% + some pixel value that's less than 20%.  With trying to guestimate the pixel value that will always be less than 20%, you introduce unnecessary complexity that may result in incorrect sizing later on.  It's especially problematic on responsive applications because you are usually setting the width to be 100% of some column or container.  For narrower screens, you're more likely to see your pixel value exceed that 20% ceiling.  In the end, it's just simpler to make your two columns 50%.

Comment: Oh, i thought you meant the box-sizing bit, but that makes sense too. thanks for the info.

Comment: @BrianM. You're welcome. Glad I could help. for `box-sizing`, It kind of goes hand in hand.  Without the `box-sizing`, the browser calculates the width as 50% of the parent + 10px of left padding, which given a 100px wide container  will result in a 60px wide column (50px of width and 10px of padding).  With `box-sizing:border-box`, it includes the padding when it calculates the width, so in that same scenario, 50% means 50px (40px of width and 10px of padding).  The opposite of `border-box` is `content-box` and it is the default.